# Magento form submit problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a form  with different different button when ever i click it should submit same page it self

```
<?php if ($status != 'canceled'){?>

                                        <?php $orderIdForm = $order->getId(); ?>
                                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber/',array('id' =>$orderIdForm))?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">
                                        <?php 
                                        $tracking=$this->getTrackingNumber($order->getId());
                                        if($tracking!=""){
                                            $disabled=$tracking->getTrackingNumber()==''? "":"readonly='readonly'";
                                            $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
                                            $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
                                            $shippingamount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                                        }?>



                                    <div class="shipping_top" style="display:none">
                                        <span class="shipping_service"><?php echo $helper->__('Carrier');?></span>
                                        <span class="row_total"><?php echo $helper->__('Tracking Number');?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="items">
                                    <input class="required-entry" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order->getId(); ?>" name="order_id"/>
                                    <div class="wk_item">
                                        <span class="carrier" style="display:none"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>
                                        <span class="row_total wk_track_input" style="display:none">
                                            <!-- <input value="<?php //echo $tracking->getTrackingNumber(); ?>" <?php //echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="tracking_id"/> -->
                                            <input value="0" type="text" name="tracking_id"/>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="order-status">
                                        <?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
                                            <?php if($status=="Ordered"): ?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                                    <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                                        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif;  ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if($status == "processing" ){?>

                                            <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Generate Invoice') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
                                                <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice') ?></span></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php } ?>


                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->
                                        <?php if ($status == "Invoice"){?>

                                        <!-- <a href="<?php //echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>"> -->
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        <!-- </a>  -->
                                        <?php }?>


                                        <?php if ($status == 'Shipement'){?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php }?>

                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->





                                            </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Here **invoice** button is working but **Shipment** not working. I am using wrong way can you please tell what is the problem in this?

Comment: post this method too `savetrackingnumber` problem in this method not in form.

Comment: then what i need to use

Comment: post in question so i can figured out where is the problem..

Comment: can i update the question???

Comment: yes you can update that..

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: r u talking about this code? `<?php if ($status == 'Shipement'){?>
                                      <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span>
              </button>
         </a>
                                        <?php }?>`

Comment: no shipment  <?php if ($status == 'Shipement'){?>
              <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span>
                </button>
              </a>
              <?php }?>

Comment: i think problem is form action

Comment: Let us assume one form have multiple button with different url i need to submit same page it self

Comment: in your code from is submitting with one url other button have `<a>` tag they are working like links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php if ($status == 'Shipement'){?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>‌​"> <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" > <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span> </button> </a> <?php }?>
```

replace with

```
<?php if ($status == 'Shipement'){?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>‌​"> <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" > <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span> </button> </a> <?php }?>
```

Comment: what is difference between my code and this

Comment: you adding the wrong variable. the correct variable is `$orderIdForm`. the page is goes blank because of missing id..

Comment: i tried this also in yesterday anyway ok thank for your help

Comment: glad i can help..

Comment: is it correct <?php if($invoiceId): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/printinvoice',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?>" id="<?php echo $orderIdForm; ?>" style="float:right;">
            <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?></span></span>
           </button></a>
           <?php endif; ?> it download invoice slip bt it redirect to blank page

Comment: yes it is correct but check the redirect and add this `$this->_redirectReferer();` for redirect

Comment: public function printinvoiceAction() { if ($invoice_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {  if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice_id)) {   $pdf = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
                 $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s'). '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');

                 $this->_redirectReferer();
             }
         }
         else {
             $this->_forward('noRoute');
         }
     }

Comment: get invoice id and send that in param

Comment: Yes but we are using order id in phtml right?

Comment: you can get invoice id from order id.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get invoice id from order id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032315/how-to-get-invoice-id-from-order-increment-id

Comment: i can get in this way echo $orderid = $orderIdForm; // order increment id
echo $orderss = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid); how to add that invoice slip link

Comment: sorry don't get you?

Comment: actually i get increment id with this how to load here <?php if($invoiceId): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/printinvoice',array('invoice_id'=>$orderss));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;">
     <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: you loading the order id again not loading the invoice id's

Comment: $invIncrementIDs this is invoice id right

Comment: <?php 

           echo $orderid = $orderIdForm; // order increment id
echo $orderss = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    $invIncrementIDs = array();
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($invIncrementIDs);
echo "</pre>"; ?>

Comment: simple use this `$invIncrementIDs[0]` for params

Comment: i nned to add this in controller file or phtml file can you please update it

Comment: public function printAction()
     {
         if ($shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) { // invoice_id o_0
             if ($shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId)) {
                 $pdf = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/order_pdf_shipment')->getPdf(array($shipment));
                 $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('packingslip'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
             }
         }
         else {
             $this->_forward('noRoute');
         }
     }

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100080/invoice-slip-not-working

Comment: If you are free please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100221/problem-in-shopping-cart-page

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber/',array('id' =>$orderIdForm))?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">       

<?php if($status == "processing" ){?>
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Generate Invoice') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice') ?></span></span>
</button>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($status == "Invoice"){?>
<button style="" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>')" class="button wk_mp_btn" type="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="id-wk-mp-btn"><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span></button> 
<?php }?>

</form>
```

Comment: No it's redirect in this domain.com/mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber/id/1986/ and it show blank page not submiting

Comment: on click Shipment Button right??

Comment: yes it should not redirect, it should submit current page itself

Comment: Pls add bellow code after </form> tag : <?php if ($status == "Invoice"){?>
<button style="" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>')" class="button wk_mp_btn" type="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="id-wk-mp-btn"><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span></button> 
<?php }?>

Comment: i added it load ajax not submiting

Comment: Pls share all code with ajax 
in qus

Comment: Check my updated question it should not submit ajax

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100080/invoice-slip-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You have a type="button" instead of type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

change your **shipment button code** from

```
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
```

to

```
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
```

Comment: As a note misspelling `float` won't help you with CSS

Comment: it redirect not working