# Invoice slip not working

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, invoice

I download invoice slip it's not working

```
<?php $orderIdForm = $order->getId(); ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber/',array('id' =>$orderIdForm))?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">

    <?php if ($status == 'Invoice'){?> 
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipmentorder',array('id'=>$orderIdForm))?>‌​"> <button class="button" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="button"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span> </button> 
        </a>
         <?php }?> 
    <?php if($invoiceId): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/printinvoice',array('invoice_id'=>$invoiceId));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;">
    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

        </form>
```

**controller**

```
public function printinvoiceAction()
    {
        if ($invoice_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) { 
            if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice_id)) {                  
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
                $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                    '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');

                $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
```

it redirect to blank page But invoice page is not working this page only problem

Comment: can post the html output of this code? html code only

Comment: <?php if($invoiceId): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/printinvoice',array('invoice_id'=>$invoiceId));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;">
    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice Slip') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: output want not the code bro.. what is wshowing on webpage

Comment: domain.com/mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber/id/1992/ it redirect to blank page

Comment: because of this code `else {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }` you are redirect to blank

Comment: How to fix this ?

Comment: no need to fix your else condition is working not if

Comment: but invoice page it's working this page only it's not working

Comment: `$invoiceId` output of this?

Comment: it shows 1179...

Comment: `printinvoiceAction` action is yours not the `printAction`

Comment: i didn't get i used printinvoiceAction only

Comment: you posted the wrong controller action

Comment: sorry i updated check now

Comment: What is the problem on this

Comment: try `echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id'); exit;` and check what out you are getting

Comment: Can i use phtml or controller file

Comment: in your controller action put this code check the output

Comment: it redirect to another page that shows 1180

Comment: @QaisarSatti what is the problem here

Comment: in invoice page it redirect to another page that shows 1180 & My order history page it redirect to blank page

Comment: Now both place download not working i don't know what is the problem

Comment: remove the change and check this will go in if condition?

Comment: yes i removed i nner  page also not working now

Comment: i added this $this->_redirectReferer(); so that it's not working

Comment: front page not working how to fix that

Comment: where you added that and do you know what this code is doing?

Comment: i added controller file this code redirect to same page it self

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: i put inside the form so that it's not working