# +/- Problem in Shopping cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I used Increment & Decrement qty in Shopping Cart page

```
   <div class="qty-ctl">    
    <button title="Decrease Qty" onclick="changeQty1('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',0); return false;" class="decrease"><?php echo $this->__('decrease') ?></button>    
</div>      

    <input id="<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />

<div class="qty-ctl">         
    <button title="Increase Qty" onclick="changeQty1('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',1); return false;" class="increase"><?php echo $this->__('increase') ?></button>       
</div>
```

**Script**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
             function changeQty(id, num) {
    var qty_id = id;

    var currentVal = parseInt($(qty_id).value);
    if (currentVal != NaN)
    {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode != 13) {
        $(qty_id).value = currentVal + num;
    }
         document.getElementById("scart").submit();
    }
}





function changeQty1(id, num) {
        var qty_id = id;

        var currentVal = parseInt($(qty_id).value);
        if (currentVal != NaN)
        {

            if(num != 0) {
                $(qty_id).value = currentVal + 1;
            }else {
                $(qty_id).value = currentVal - 1;
           }
             document.getElementById("scart").submit();
        }
    }
            </script>
```

in here Manual entry is working but  +/- Button Not working i don't know what is the problem?

Comment: Try following this tutorial: http://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/08/add-increase-and-decrease-quantity-buttons-to-items-in-magento-cart/

Comment: Check now i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeQty(id, num) {
    var qty_id = id;

    var currentVal = parseInt($(qty_id).value);
    if (currentVal != NaN)
    {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode != 13) {
        $(qty_id).value = currentVal + num;
    }

    }
}
```

make different function for both  for button use `changeQty1`

```
function changeQty1(id, num) {
        var qty_id = id;

        var currentVal = parseInt($(qty_id).value);
        if (currentVal != NaN)
        {

            if(num != 0) {
                $(qty_id).value = currentVal + 1;
            }else {
                $(qty_id).value = currentVal - 1;
           }
             document.getElementById("scart").submit();
        }
    }


<div class="qty-ctl">    
        <button title="Decrease Qty" type="button"  onclick="changeQty1('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',0); return false;" class="decrease"><?php echo $this->__('decrease') ?></button>    
    </div>      

        <input id="<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" onblur="document.getElementById('scart').submit()" />

    <div class="qty-ctl">         
        <button title="Increase Qty" type="button" onclick="changeQty1('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',1); return false;" class="increase"><?php echo $this->__('increase') ?></button>       
    </div>
```

Comment: increment/decrement button not working

Comment: do you have live links website?

Comment: try now updated the code..

Comment: bro now manual enter qty not working if i enter 5 the press enter it automatically reduced 4

Comment: updated code check and feedback me

Comment: same problem increment/decrement button not working check that link

Comment: use different function  for both see the updated answer just follow it

Comment: Check my updated question same problem check that link also

Comment: it is working fine what you want now? + /1 and also direct entry is working

Comment: in that text box type 2 and press enter

Comment: remove `document.getElementById("scart").submit();` from first function update answer

Comment: i updated but still same check that link

Comment: Problem is when ever we press enter that time next button is pressed so this is the problem

Comment: remove this function from enter because already they are in form if you press enter form will be submitted automatically did you try that?

Comment: Where i need to remove this

Comment: kindly add `button type="button"` updated the answer

Comment: if it's 1 product in cart it's working fine if more then one it's not working

Comment: add some code in input field add it and feedback me

Comment: Bro Now Manual enter not working

Comment: `onblur="document.getElementById('scart').submit()"` use single update this and check

Comment: Single product is working but more then one not working

Comment: i check with multiple product it is working but it is working on blur function mean after you input and leave the input field it's update i test on ur website

Comment: +/- is working but manual enter not working check that link

Comment: i check for both they are working fine bro

Comment: if enter manually then press enter amount should increase but it's not increase like +/-

Comment: it will not increase like on enter form will be submit and add quantity automatically..

Comment: sorry i didn't get

Comment: you press enter it mean form submit not increase the quantity. enter equal to submit button

Comment: NO actually i want on that way only if type qty and press enter amount also should increase even page reload also not a problem

Comment: Because we don't have update cart option

Comment: now it is doing on blur function updating the cart quantity not the enter button add quantity click on page it will update the quantity of product..

Comment: i didn't get you u[date answer

Comment: last code i gave to is `onblur` js function it is working fine. i checked your link with multiple product it working fine

Comment: yes but after enter amount also should increase but it's not increasing

Comment: there is not function defined for enter press.

Comment: I have a doubt is it possible http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99994/magento-custom-order

Comment: yes it is possible bro just override the block and your lifetime sales

Comment: can you please give a code on that

Comment: you want to remove order the rto state from life time saving?

Comment: yes if admin click amount should reduce

Comment: admin click where click can you tell me whole?

Comment: it's one of the order status if customer not available while deliver time so product return to inventory so admin put rto status for that order it wil be available in sales order page

Comment: Did you check this ?http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99994/magento-custom-order

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code like below

```
<div class="quantity"> 
        <button id="subtractQty" class="decrease"><?php echo $this->__('decrease') ?></button> 
        <input readonly name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" id="qty"/>
        <button id="addQty" class="increase"><?php echo $this->__('increase') ?></button>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#addQty").click(function() {
        var value = parseInt(jQuery("#qty").val())+ parseInt(1);    
        jQuery("#qty").val(value);                                  
    });

    jQuery("#subtractQty").click(function() {
        if(jQuery("#qty").val() > 1 ) {
            var value = parseInt(jQuery("#qty").val())- parseInt(1);    
            jQuery("#qty").val(value);      
        }
    });                                

</script>
```

Comment: This code not works when you have 2 products or more because you play with id's

Comment: But Manual enter qty not working

Comment: I have updated my answer please try with this one

Comment: Let as assume i have 2 product in cart 1st product qty i type 10 and then enter it automatically change into 9 second is working fine